# How to Update a MongoDB Record with an Existing Value From Same Record

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query to update a date in mongo to be the same as an existing date inside of the same record based on some logic. I have a simple step that I am stuck on how do I access the value?

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection").updateMany({
//SOME LOGIC HERE
{
"$set":{"updatedTs": "$$createdTs"}
},{multi:true}
)
```

This returns updatedTs being equal to the literal string "$$createdTs" and not the value stored. The closest I've found to my query is this forum question but the page linked no longer exists: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/updatemany-in-mongodb-using-value-of-other-field/99555

What am I missing here?

Comment: use the set the aggregation way with `[{"$set": {"updatedTs": ...}}]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/13583510

Comment: @cmgchess Thank you! I will take a look. Looks like I missed the aggregate brackets.

Comment: Thanks that's what was missing! I needed to add [] around set before {multi:true} and remove one of the $ in createdTs. That worked. I can accept your answer if you want to write that. This has puzzled me for a whole day thank you!

Comment: sure i added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from MongoDB 4.2 onwards you can write aggregation pipeline inside update queries (i.e includes [`updateMany`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-update-many-method-agg-pipeline)).

```js
db.getCollection("MyCollection").updateMany({
//SOME LOGIC HERE
},
[
 {
  "$set":{"updatedTs": "$createdTs"}
 }
],
{multi:true}
)
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_LQZKfPKxAr)