# $Subtract and other artihmetic operators returning Object instead of int

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

### Problem

- I made some code to perform arithmetic operations as I am working on billing software.
- This code snippet is causing issues

```js
    await shopCollection.updateOne(
            { Barcode: elem.Barcode },
            {
              $set: {
                Quantity: { $subtract: ["$Quantity", #elem.Quantity] },
                SalesQuantity: {
                  $add: [{ $ifNull: ["$SalesQuantity", 0] }, elem.Quantity],
                },
                Profit: { $subtract: ["$SalesPrice", "$CostPrice"] },
                TotalProfit: {
                  $add: ["$TotalProfit", { $multiply: ["$Profit", elem.Quantity] }],
                },
                SalesTotal: {
                  $add: [
                    "$SalesTotal",
                    { $multiply: ["$SalesPrice", elem.Quantity] },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
          );
```

Entire code : https://pastebin.com/b6Zzhv16

### It returns a object instead of Int like so

[image: comparison Image]

- I am using ubuntu ,running the mongodb community edition and I am not using mongoose or schemas

Comment: try doing set using aggregation pipeline like `[{$set:...}]` ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76212206/how-to-update-a-mongodb-record-with-an-existing-value-from-same-record/76212370#76212370

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid this you will have to use [aggregation pipeline with the `updateOne` operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#std-label-update-one-method-agg-pipeline).

Apart from that few issues I found

1. Since you are creating the `Profit` field inside the `$set` and you are trying to refer to that field in the same `$set` you will have to do in a new pipeline `$set` stage.
2. Since you don't have `TotalProfit` profit field in your initial data you will have to write an `ifNull` check before adding otherwise you end up with `null`

```js
await shopCollection.updateOne({
  Barcode: elem.Barcode
},
[
  {
    $set: { 
      Quantity: { $subtract: [ "$Quantity", elem.Quantity ] },
      SalesQuantity: { $add: [ { $ifNull: [ "$SalesQuantity", 0 ] }, elem.Quantity ] },
      Profit: { $subtract: [ "$SalesPrice", "$CostPrice" ] },
      SalesTotal: { $add: [ "$SalesTotal", { $multiply: [ "$SalesPrice", elem.Quantity ] } ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      TotalProfit: { $add: [ { $ifNull: [ "$TotalProfit", 0 ] }, { $multiply: [ "$Profit", elem.Quantity ] } ] }
    }
  }
],
  { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
);
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1kzj2DpWdYy)